# Difference between 1. Poetry add <package> vs 2. a) Poetry shell then b) pip install <package>

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-poetry

I am wondering what is the difference when we do `poetry add <package>` vs spawning a shell in the virtual env using `poetry shell` and then installing using pip `pip install <package>`. One difference I can spot is `pip install` method does not add the package to "pyproject.toml" file. However, after doing the pip install from the poetry shell, when I do `poetry add <same package>`, poetry does recognize the package has already been installed and it does add the package information in the dependency file.

The reason for doing this is few packages do not work with the `poetry add` method on my system but work with the `pip install` method. Hence wanted to get a better understanding of what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Probably a better question would have been if you asked: "I can install this package [link] with `pip install`, but not with `poetry add`. But using Pip doesn't add the package to pyproject.toml, and Poetry is not (fully) aware of the package. How do I get Poetry to add this package as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"poetry add " is used in place of "pip install "; "poetry shell" is the command used to activate the virtual environment...

here is some good reading on virtual environments (and how to use poetry specifically):

- https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/
- https://python-poetry.org/docs/

Comment: This does not answer the question...  and does not explain why (as I noticed too) "few packages do not work with the poetry add method on my system but work with the pip install method"

Comment: question was modified post answer.

Comment: `poetry add` wraps around Pip to do many things, while when doing `poetry shell` + `pip install` you won't do exactly the same thing as Poetry. I don't know the details, and without details about whick packages are troublesome, I can't tell more ...